# What can I do do address a regression with systematic bias towards the middle?

Tags: scikit-learn, linear-regression

I’ve created a linear regression but my predicted output is usually too low for true high values and too high for true low values. I’ve tried introducing a pipeline where I use polynomial features, which generally improved performance, but that particular bias remained.

Please see my notebook and help advise: [Solar Panel Model on GitHub] (https://github.com/Tareq62/solar_panel_model/blob/master/solar_regression.ipynb)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to fit data that is fundamentally non-linear, to a straight line. If you just look at daylight hours over a year, it's roughly quadratic. This is coupled with the fact that linear regression will minimize errors from each data point to the mean, which is what you're observing.

[image: Daylight Hours]

You can still do "linear" regression, but add in polynomial powers of other features

```
poly = preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures(degree=2)
scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler()
lin_reg2 = linear_model.LinearRegression()

pipeline_reg = pipeline.Pipeline([
    ('poly', poly),
    ('scal', scaler),
    ('lin', lin_reg2)])
pipeline_reg.fit(Xfull, yfull)
```

Note that this will increase the time it takes to train proportionally to the number of additional features.